# WhatsApp Video call notification logic

Tags: ios, callkit, pushkit

I have an application that is using VoIP, PushKit, and CallKit, the client needs the reported incoming video call like WhatsApp video call notification.

The problem that I'm facing when PushKit receive a notification and my app doesn't report an incoming call to the CallKit the app will crash.

I tried to understand how WhatsApp did this trick, but no luck on the web.

Any advice or idea will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Very simple - you should avoid situations where you receive a PushKit notification without reporting an incoming call.

Even if you don't want to report this call, you can report an incoming call with caller name "Connection failed..." or something like that.